# How to Merge user controls that Binds to SAME obj smoothly?

Tags: wpf, mvvm, data-binding, merge, user-controls

I'm trying to merge some user controls that are binded to same target. At the start, it looks simple but I have no idea with this how can I deliver binding target to daughter control (controls inside merge control)?

I want to make this:

```
    <Canvas>
        <local:Teeth x:Name="sideR" Points="{Binding Points[0]}" IsClosedCurve="{Binding IsClosedCurve}"/>
        <local:WrapTeeth Points="{Binding Points[0]}"/>
        <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Points[0]}" ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource PointListBoxItemStyle}">
            <ListBox.Template>
                <ControlTemplate>
                    <Canvas IsItemsHost="True"/>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </ListBox.Template>
        </ListBox>
    </Canvas>
```

into

```
    <local:MergeControl Points="{Binding Points[0]}"/>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your UserControl should have a `Points` dependency property like shown below. It is not clear from your question whether you need a more specialized collection type than `IEnumerable`. Possibly replace it with `PointCollection` or something more suitable.

```
public partial class MergeControl : UserControl
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty PointsProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
        "Points", typeof(IEnumerable), typeof(MergeControl));

    public IEnumerable Points
    {
        get { return (IEnumerable)GetValue(PointsProperty); }
        set { SetValue(PointsProperty, value); }
    }

    public MergeControl()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

The elements in the UserControl's XAML would bind to this property by `RelativeSource` Bindings. You may need to define another property for the `IsClosedCurve` Binding of the `Teeth` element.

```
<UserControl ...>
    <UserControl.Resources>
        <Style x:Key="PointListBoxItemStyle" TargetType="ListBoxItem">
            ...
        </Style>
    </UserControl.Resources>
    <Canvas>
        <local:Teeth x:Name="sideR"
            Points="{Binding Points, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}}"
            IsClosedCurve="{Binding IsClosedCurve, ...}"/>

        <local:WrapTeeth
            Points="{Binding Points, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}}"/>

        <ListBox
            ItemsSource="{Binding Points, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}}"
            ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource PointListBoxItemStyle}">
            <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <Canvas/>
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
        </ListBox>
    </Canvas>
</UserControl>
```

Note also that ItemsControls have an `ItemsPanel` property to set the Panel element that is used to contain their items.

Comment: thanks alot @Clemens it definately helps me. ill remember to use keyword RelativeSource incase like this next time